# Does Firefox stop running JavaScript when minimized (longpolling)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, minimize

I have a longpoll running but when I open a new tab in Firefox, or minimize the browser the longpoll seems to time out!? However if I leave the tab selected, or make a new dedicated window with Firefox open it won't time out.

Does anyone have any thought or insight on this weird behavior? When minimzied/alternate tab does Firefox stop running JavaScript in those tabs?

By the way I'm using Firefox 3.6.

Comment: FYI I FIGURED IT OUT. THE PROBLEM IS THAT THE JAVASCRIPT COULD NOT MANIPULATE THE DOM FOR SOME REASON WHEN TAB DID NOT HAVE FOCUS.

Comment: Really, you should post what kind of code you are running. Your comment seems to imply the script involves widget focus.

Comment: very useful information, +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

No, **it does not stop running JavaScript**. And It does not block you from modifying the DOM. I have an app that runss a poll on server (I have both synchronous and async transmission) and then updates the dom based on results. And if I am looking at the tab or nor, and even if the firefox 3.6 is minimized - it just works. I have just tested it (again), before posting this answer.

Even the javascript test tools like *selenium* (in javascript) that are manipulating the DOM are working without focus.

So please check your code, it probably does require focus on some tab or on some element (like **syockit** suggested). I belive that you have the firebug, and you can easily analyze and debug your javascript (if it is not obfuscated).

Comment: Perhaps I was too vague. More sepcifically, it blocked me from destroying a DOM node with a flash player in it then using SWFObject to load a new one in -- it couldn't load the new one. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ohh, now it's more complicated, now you have a flash plugin on a page, and you are using SWFObject. Honestly, I do not know how it works. But, you can try two write some test cases in selenium, then you will have a specific scenario, and a simple test you can share with others. Have you tried looking the answer on Mozilla pages? Or in Mozilla Bug tracking tool.